# JPA Entities shared between several applications (Wildfly - Hibernate - Maven)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

Is there a way to configure various persistence.xml contained in different applications (war or ear) that all use a shared jar that contains all entities?

Something like:

```
  deployments/
    |-ArchiviBase.war
      |-WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml
      |-WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\TipoAbitazione.hbm.xml
    |-Application2.war
      |-WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml
    |-Application3.war
      |-WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml
  lib/
    |-models.jar
      |- it\test\archiviBase\beans\TipoAbitazione.java
```

With all files (persistence.xml, hbm.xml and java class) within the war the mapping works correctly, but I need to share java entities with all applications, so I would like to move them to models.jar.

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="archiviBasePU">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jdbc/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
                            value="java:jboss/hibernate/app1SF" />
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name"
                            value="java:/hibernate/app1SF" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema"
                            value="app_schema" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**TipoAbitazione.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping auto-import="true"
    default-access="property" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
    <class dynamic-insert="false" dynamic-update="false"
        mutable="true"
        name="it.test.app1.beans.TipoAbitazione"
        optimistic-lock="version" polymorphism="implicit"
        select-before-update="false" table="tipo_abitazione">
        <id column="tpab_codice" name="codice" type="java.lang.String">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property column="tpab_descrizione" generated="never"
            lazy="false" length="100" name="descrizione" not-null="true"
            optimistic-lock="true" type="java.lang.String" unique="false" />
        <property column="tpab_flag_attivo" generated="never"
            lazy="false" length="1" name="attivo" optimistic-lock="true"
            type="java.lang.Boolean" unique="false" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**TipoAbitazione.java**

```
package it.test.archiviBase.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
 
public class TipoAbitazione implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String codice;
    private String descrizione;
    private Boolean attivo;

    public TipoAbitazione() {
    }

    public TipoAbitazione(String codice, String descrizione) {
        this.codice = codice;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public TipoAbitazione(String codice, String descrizione, Boolean attivo) {
        this.codice = codice;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.attivo = attivo;
    }

    public String getCodice() {
        return this.codice;
    }

    public void setCodice(String codice) {
        this.codice = codice;
    }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return this.descrizione;
    }

    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }

    public Boolean getAttivo() {
        return this.attivo;
    }

    public void setAttivo(Boolean attivo) {
        this.attivo = attivo;
    }
}
```

Each application should define its own persistence unit, using its own hbm.xml files, but the java entities will all be contained in the shared models.jar file

**This is the error when I try to deploy the war:**

> 1-03-25 15:20:46,406 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService
> Thread Pool -- 3) MSC000001: Failed to start service
> jboss.persistenceunit."archiviBaseTest2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#archiviBasePU":
> org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.persistenceunit."archiviBaseTest2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#archiviBasePU":
> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> archiviBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:198)
> at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:128)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
> at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:213)
> at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513) Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> archiviBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1327)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1253)
> at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
> at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:170)
> ... 10 more Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
> at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
> at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
> at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:154)
> at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:295)
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467)
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1250)
> ... 12 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer
> [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:413)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:557)
> at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
> ... 17 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)
> ... 26 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
> at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:154)
> at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:365)
> at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:174)
> at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:376)
> at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.load(ByteBuddyState.java:183)
> at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.loadProxy(ByteBuddyState.java:107)
> at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyHelper.buildProxy(ByteBuddyProxyHelper.java:54)
> at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyProxyFactory.postInstantiate(ByteBuddyProxyFactory.java:62)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:103)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:155)
> at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:51)
> ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking Unsafe::defineClass
> at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$Enabled.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:1997)
> at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe.injectRaw(ClassInjector.java:1774)
> at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$AbstractBase.inject(ClassInjector.java:112)
> at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$ForUnsafeInjection.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:546)
> at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:100)
> at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:5662)
> at org.hibernate.bytecode.internal.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyState.lambda$load$0(ByteBuddyState.java:187)
> at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:152)
> ... 41 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
> at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassInjector$UsingUnsafe$Dispatcher$Enabled.defineClass(ClassInjector.java:1987)
> ... 48 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module
> "deployment.external.global-directory.lib" from Service Module Loader]
> at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
> at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
> ... 54 more
>
> 2021-03-25 15:20:46,411 ERROR
> [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management
> Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address:
> ([("deployment" => "archiviBaseTest2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure
> description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.persistenceunit."archiviBaseTest2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#archiviBasePU""
> => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: archiviBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: archiviBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate
> SessionFactory
> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking Unsafe::defineClass
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module
> "deployment.external.global-directory.lib" from Service Module
> Loader]"}} 2021-03-25 15:20:46,412 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server]
> (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of
> deployment "archiviBaseTest2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with
> the following failure message: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" =>
> {"jboss.persistenceunit."archiviBaseTest2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war#archiviBasePU""
> => "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: archiviBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: archiviBasePU] Unable to build Hibernate
> SessionFactory
> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for
> org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error invoking Unsafe::defineClass
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module
> "deployment.external.global-directory.lib" from Service Module
> Loader]"}}

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Define persistence unit -->
<persistence-unit name="archiviBasePU">
    ...
    <jar-file>models.jar</jar-file>
    ...
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: I've already tried with the jar-file tag, which I believe is the right way, but I get the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: The error seems unrelated to this. Isn't it a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy`? It means that hibernate-core is missing on the classpath

Comment: I want to use the version of Hibernate provided by Wildfly. Why if I put all the files in the war is everything loaded correctly? How can I add hibernate-core to models.jar?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `persistence.xml` in the same library as the loaded classes if you don't want to have to explicitly list them in the persistence.xml of every application.

Comment: If I explicitly list the class with `<class>it.test.app1.beans.TipoAbitazione</class>` in the persistence.xml I got the same error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy from [Module \"deployment.external.global-directory.lib\" from Service Module Loader]"}}`. I'm using Hibernate provided by WildFly.